# App closes (not crash) in release mode but works fine in debug mode while implementing google sign in

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services

I am trying to implement Google Sign-In but my app closes (goes to On-Pause STATE)
right after google play sign in dialog pops up.

The catch is that it runs fine when in debug mode but the problem arises only in release mode.

Here is a gif of what's happening:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B0KiKeLJdCDVejNLYlZvU19sdk0/view?usp=sharing

I also found something on a page that I fail to understand:

Warning: When you run the application directly from Android Studio, Android Studio will sign the application with your debug certificate by default. If you did not use this debug certificate when setting up the application in Google Play Developer Console, this will cause errors. Make sure to run an APK that you exported and signed with a certificate that matches one of the certificates you used during the application setup in Google Play Developer Console.

source: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/quickstart#step_3_modify_your_code

Search for the below on play store if you want to experience the problem:
nxstudio.com.homeless

Edit: My LOG

04-24 18:35:30.943 4004-4850/? E/TokenRequestor: You have wrong OAuth2 related configurations, please check. Detailed error: UNREGISTERED_ON_API_CONSOLE

04-24 18:35:31.023 9163-9163/? E/TAGERER: Could not connect to Play games services

Any help will be most appreciated,
Thanks in Advance

Comment: post logcat when app closes..

Comment: @DivyeshPatel I have posted the relevant log, can you help me

Comment: you forgot to add token in console. go to your OAuth2 console and add relevant information in it.

Comment: can you give me the link to that console

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41454060/6756514

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40988326/6756514

Comment: thanks create a small post so I can upvote

Comment: check : http://stackoverflow.com/a/41012703/6756514

Answer (score 0):

you need to enable OAuth2 from console for your Signed apk and also use same SHA that used for generate signed APK.