# Why doesn't my deployed Android app sign into Google Play Services, while my debug app does?

Tags: android, authentication, google-play-games

My Android app's login to Google Play Games services seems to fail silently: after choosing the user in the sign-in activity, `onActivityResult()` receives a `resultCode` value of 10002. The Android APIs deposit these messages in the logcat:

```
W/SignInActivity(16216): onSignInFailed()...
W/SignInActivity(16216): Sign in failed during 6
W/SignInActivity(16216): ==> Returning non-OK result: 10002
```

while Log.w() commands I placed in `onActivityResult()` deposit these messages:

```
W/Main activity(16167): In activity result with code 10002
W/Main activity(16167): activity result requests sign in
W/Main activity(16167): unsolved resolution
```

The strange thing is that it used to work, and when I try to debug it from Android Studio, login works perfectly *every time*, so I can't even debug the app!

Where can I get started debugging this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to [a problem with the same error but a completely different cause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453911/google-play-game-service-failing-to-sign-in), but this situation is different in that it was caused by activating a feature in the Google Play Developer Console.

The keys to this particular error are that:

1. The production app *used* to work properly, but doesn't any more.
2. The debug version *still* works properly.

Back in May, Google introduced a feature wherein [they sign your app in the Play Store](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#google-play-app-signing). My original app was signed with the certificate generated by Android Studio, but Google seems pretty gung-ho about their signing so I switched to that without reading the fine print very carefully. As a result:

- For the debug app, the Google Play Games API expected the debug certificate, and Android Studio still used that certificate to generate a debug apk, so the Games API routinely accepted sign-in while debugging.
- For the production app, the API expected the Android Studio-generated production certificate, which Android Studio happily supplied, but Google Play replaced with its own certificate, so the Games API routinely rejected sign-in.

The solution is to:

- stop cursing;
- visit the App signing option under Release management in the [usual Play Store developer Console](https://play.google.com/apps/publish/);
- copy the SHA-1 fingerprint under "App signing certificate" (**not** the fingerprint "Upload certificate" -- that's what got you into this mess);
- visit the Credentials page at [Google's site for developers](http://console.developers.google.com/apis/)
- select your app
- paste the certificate you just copied into the text field labeled "Signing-certificate fingerprint." (The field itself is below some instructions on how to extract it from your keystore -- **don't** use those instructions when Google signs your app!)

At this point the deployed version worked for me like magic. No programming required!